# Is it hard or easy to find a hard-coded encrypt algorithm and password in a compiled iOS/Android app

Tags: android, ios, delphi, encryption, firemonkey

Is it hard or easy to find a hard-coded encryption algorithm and password in a compiled delphi *iOS* and *Android* app? On *Windows* we have plenty of tool to disassemble *Win32*/*Win64* compiled exe, but what about *iOS* and *Android*?

I want the app to perform some operations and send me the results, but I want to be (more or less) sure that the client will not alter the result himself. This why I think about let the app encrypt the result in such way that only the server app knows how to decrypt it. But if the client can be decompiled easily then off course he can send me anything he wants, if he know how to encrypt the data

Comment: I guess it depends on what type of encryption you're using, and what library, if any, is implementing it. As far as your password? How are you storing it?

Comment: @JerryDodge Right now i don't know yet what to use and how to do. I can use RSA algorithm for exemple and a hard coded key

Comment: It's easy for a hacker to crack what you are proposing. Use SSL.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: How SSL can forbid the user to send me data he himself modified instead of the data that the application have calculated ?

Comment: OK, you are right. This is what happens when people that know nothing about security try to do security.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan no problem I don't know too this why I m here to learn !

Comment: @loki Please don't see Stack Overflow as a learning site. It's rather a resource of specific questions/answers to help many others with similar issues. This question isn't quite at that value level.

Comment: @whosrdaddy: how can certificates and root CA can help me here ? I don't understand ...

Comment: @whosrdaddy I still not see how to make it working :( i m in the server and i need to be sure the the request is made by my app and not made by the someone else.. the link you gave me is the opposite, it's to be sure that the answer come from the server

Comment: Loki, you are almost there: in SSL, the server always presents a certificate to prove that it is the right server. The point of mutually-authenticated SSL (where both the server and the client have certificates) is for the device to prove to the server that it is the right device...

Comment: I suggest to read [this stackexchange article](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work), and more specifically, the part about Message Authentication, which is the part you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 3):

1. On iOS obtaining an embedded password is difficult but not impossible. iOS can not be decompiled but a debugger can be attached to a loaded app and the executing object code examined.
2. The encryption algorithm does not need to be secret and making it secret does not provide additional security.
3. RSA is not suitable for data encryption because the data size is limited to less than the key size and it is very slow. For data encryption AES is the preferred method with no size limitation and it is fast.